# Problema para mostrar columnas con eager loading

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo el siguiente método para devolver a cada usuario con todos sus posts asociados, auxiliandome de `eager loading`

```
public function data() {
        $data = User::with(['posts' => function($query){
            $query->select('namePost');
        }])->get();
        return $data;
    }
```

Sin embargo al momento de obtener los registros, me da esto como resultado

```
{
"id": 1,
"nameUser": "user",
"passwordUser": "secret",
"statusUser": 1,
"created_at": "2019-01-20 10:16:13",
"posts": []
}
```

Donde como pueden notar no me devuelve la columna deseada, sin embargo si hago lo siguiente

```
public function data() {
        $data = User::with(['posts' => function($query){
            $query->select('posts.*');
        }])->get();
        return $data;
    }
```

Me devuelve todas las columnas, ¿cómo logro seleccionar solo determinadas columnas?

Lo he intentado de este modo también:

```
$data = User::with('posts:id, namePost')->get();
```

Pero sigo sin conseguir las columnas deseadas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de investigar un rato, encontré que es necesario colocar la `FK` que asocia a la tabla dependiente con la tabla principal.

En este caso en la tabla `Posts` la `FOREIGN KEY` es la columna llamada `user_id`

Entonces modificando mi consulta debería quedar así:

```
public function data() {
        $data = User::with(['posts' => function($query){
            $query->select('id', 'namePost', 'user_id');
        }])->get();
        return $data;
    }
```

O también puedo hacerlo directo desde el modelo `User.php` en el método `posts` de este modo

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->select('id', 'namePost', 'user_id');
}
```

En ambos casos la `FK` es necesaria agregarla para indicar a Laravel a través de que columna vincular ambos modelos, en este caso `User` y `Post`

Si elijo el segundo modo, hacerlo directo desde el modelo, entonces mi consulta en el controlador me queda así:

```
$data = User::with('posts')->get();
```